# Как с помощью python реализовать нахождение закрытой экспоненты для RSA?

Tags: python, криптография

Пытаюсь реализовать RSA на Питоне и в процессе застрял на создании закрытого ключа. Как его можно создать, по какому алгоритму?

(В интернете смотрел, но так и не понял,  не отправляйте, пожалуйста, читать Википедию.)

Я пробовал находить ее с помощью расширенного алгоритма Евклида, но не уверен, что те ответы, которые я получал, являются правильными.

Answer (score 1):

Стандартная процедура генерации ключей RSA выглядит приблизительно так:

```
var p = randomPrime();
var q = randomPrime();

var n = p * q;
var phi = (p - 1) * (q - 1);
var e = 65537; // публичный ключ
// расширеный алгоритм Эвклида phi * x + e * y = 1
(x, y) = extEuclidean(phi, e);
var d = y;
if (d < 0) d += phi;
// d - приватный ключ
```

Comment: если честно ,то я не очень понимаю,почему у меня не работает следующий код [https://pastebin.com/vpDNM7vp ] (заранее прошу прощения за имена переменных и функций) . на расшифровку этот код не работает(простые p q мне разрешили вбивать руками )